# Меры безопасности от посторонних запросов к PHP

Tags: php

Привет. В моём проекте используются запросы ко внешнему API, от которого я получаю данные. Запрос к API инициируется при помощи отправки AJAX-запроса к PHP. Во избежание абуза API(например, кто-то будет просто спамить к PHP-файлу запросами, а мой сервер будет спамить к API, за что меня вполне справедливо могут от API отключить) я принял следующие меры:

1) В начале каждого PHP-файла я использую Response Header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://search.' . $origin); // где $origin - example.com
```

2) После того, как присланные от клиента данные существуют (проверка `isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data])`), выполняю проверку на то, является ли запрос AJAX-запросом:

```
function isAjax() {
    return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

if(isAjax()) {
  //do smth
}
```

Достаточно ли этих мер или существует какой-то более простой способ защититься от посторонних запросов?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что сделанное вас от чего то защищает ? Заголовки выставляет клиент. Вы лишь убеждаетесь, что добропорядочный браузер выполняет запрос к вам через ajax. Но обычно DDoS делается специализированными программами, которые  подделают любые заголовки.

Comment: В итоге вы не можете доверять никакой информации полученной от клиента, включая любые заголовки. Все что вы можете сделать вести статистику обращений с каждого ip-адреса и принимать меры при аномалиях

Comment: @Mike хм, единственный способ для обхода моей защиты, который я сейчас вижу - запросы к IP-адресу с подделанным заголовком Host(где вместо IP-адреса будет домен). Доступ к сайту по IP-адресу сейчас закрыт(доступ возможен только по домену). Да и сам сайт, собственно, не уязвим перед L7 DDoS-атаками. Я уже давненько не встречал HTTPS-flood. Слишком мало сейчас прокси-серверов, полноценно поддерживающих HTTPS, 301 редирект и JavaScript.

Comment: @Mike кстати говоря, именно поэтому многие выбирают бесплатный план CloudFlare, где можно включить режим **I'm Under Attack**, который включает проверку браузера на поддержку кукисов и JavaScript. Такую атаку осуществить - нужны большие затраты

Comment: @Mike одно лишь меня беспокоит, что кто-то со своего сервера при помощи PHP будет при помощи cURL спамить к моему движку непосредственно к PHP-файлам и абузить при этом запросы к API. От этого и хочу защититься.

Comment: Я могу даже банально без всяких ботов нажать F12 в любом хроме и вбить туда джаваскрипт, который будет дубасить ваш API. Все проверки на куки, аяксы и хосты, естественно, пройдут.

Comment: @andreymal а как же тогда защищаются от этого? Или просто терпят? :)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin кэширование результатов обращения к внешнему API и ограничение частоты запросов, например

Comment: Так что единственный путь: 1. убеждаемся, что клиент легитимный, у него есть все ожидаемые сессионные куки. 2. смотрим количество обращений от клиента в пределах данной сессии. Если обращается слишком часто - тут что то не так, надо принимать меры.  3. Убеждаемся что сессию просто так не установить, без авторизации пользователя, например. 4. Переносим п.2 на все сессии авторизованного пользователя

Comment: @andreymal у самого основного и критичного к абузу модуля API есть ограничение - 200 запросов в час с одного IP-адреса. Там к API передаётся клиентский IP и на их стороне фильтруется. Но это только один модуль.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin а вот надо фильтровать на **своей** стороне

Comment: Вообще, в общем случае отличить нормальный запрос от постороннего невозможно вообще никак (кому надо, тот сделает всё, чтобы посторонний запрос выглядел как нормальный, в том числе подделает все заголовки из кода в вопросе), поэтому DDoS-атаки вообще работают. Кстати, у меня есть бот, который успешно обходит вот эту вот проверку кук и js от cloudflare :)

Comment: Быть может, единственное более-менее надёжное средство различия хороших и плохих запросов — капча (которую cloudflare тоже иногда выдаёт). Но тогда, очевидно, упадёт удобство пользования сайтом

Comment: @andreymal вообще, интересная идея пришла в голову - написать нейронную сеть, которая будет собирать данные о поведении нормального пользователя и анализировать все запросы с целью выявления слишком частых запросов или, например, запросов с необычным UserAgent. Боюсь, однако, что знаний моих пока что не хватит. Но идея уже слишком интересная для того, чтобы ею заняться :)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin такие штуки тоже существуют и даже без нейронных сетей :) Только я их названий не помню)

Answer (score 5):

Эти меры никак не помогут, если кто-то решит отправить на ваш API парочку лишних запросов. Access-Control-Allow-Origin поможет, только если кто-то на другом сайте разместит форму или скрипт, чтобы слать запросы посредством браузеров клиентов, которые на этот другой сайт зайдут.

Хороший способ избежать лишних запросов к стороннему API - кэшировать ответы и использовать их некоторое время, с чем отлично поможет Memcached. Например, если это API с курсом валют и одним методом без параметров, можно сделать запрос на API, сохранить на несколько часов ответ и использовать его вместо API, а по истечению этих нескольких часов, сделать очередной запрос, и так само сохранить.

Если же пользователь может передавать какие-то данные, из-за которых запросы к API могут меняться - например, API Вконтакте для поиска музыки, где пользователь может ввести любую фразу - кэшировать запросы будет сложно или даже невозможно, в таком случае можно попробовать разные варианты (в зависимости от того, как используется API и какие у него есть возможности):

- Если API позволяет, можно загрузить из API больший объем данных меньшим количеством запросов и сохранить на своем сервере, при получении запросов от клиентов сначала искать в сохраненных данных, а затем обращаться к API, если в сохраненных данных нет того, что нужно
- Если API позволяет передавать несколько ключевых слов (например, API VK позволяет передавать сотни ID страниц пользователей для поиска страниц, чтобы избежать кучи лишних запросов по каждому ID), можно создать механизм очереди на своем сервере - сохранять все запросы от пользователей в некий стек и отправлять его раз в полсекунды / секунду / сколько нужно на API, после чего очищать
- Проверять IP-адрес клиента и ограничивать кол-во запросов по нему. Это не защитит от атак с разных IP-адресов, но по крайней мере кому-то придется потратить на плохое дело больше, чем пару минут, и не получится абузить сервер простым обновлением страницы браузера. Как слой защиты, можно использовать бесплатный Cloudflare с повышенными режимами проверки клиентов, так будет сложнее навредить вашему серверу (главное, не забудьте заблокировать запросы, которые идут не через Cloudflare)
- Если к вашему API обращаются редко, можно просто сделать глобальное ограничение по количеству запросов за определенный промежуток времени. Если наблюдается аномальный объем запросов, просто отвергать их с просьбой попробовать позже. Но стоит учесть, что при постоянном потоке запросов, ваш сервис будет, по сути, нерабочим, хоть это и не навредит вашей дружбе с тем сторонним API, так что стоит в это же время постепенно блокировать источники аномального трафика.

Но это мое, любительское мнение, думаю стоит почитать профессионалов в этой сфере.